# Having trouble rendering videos online

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video

Couple of days ago my computer started having problems with videos specially online content from YouTube and Facebook. I start the video and it start to jump frames, freeze frames, pixels turns green, audio doesn't sync with the video. screenshot for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LAlq.jpg.
sometimes reloading is enough to fix it but must of times it doesn't help.

I'm using chrome(latest version) with Win7.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection?

Comment: System specs?  Particularly useful to know would be your CPU and graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [this website](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6138475?hl=en).

> 1. Update Chrome 
>     You might need the latest version of Chrome to play your video.
> 2. Turn on JavaScript 
>     Your video might require JavaScript. YouTube videos, for example, won't run without JavaScript. 
>     **To
>      turn on JavaScript, follow the steps below:**
>
>    - Open a new Chrome browser window.
>    - Type chrome://settings/content into the address bar.
>    - In the JavaScript section, select Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended).
>    - To close the window, click Done.
>    - In the top left, click the refresh button . This will update the settings.
> 3. Reset your Internet connection 
>     Your Internet network might be causing problems with video playback. 
>     **Try resetting it:**
>
>    - Turn off your computer or mobile device.
>    - Unplug your modem and your wireless router, if it’s a separate device.
>    - Wait for about one minute.
>    - Plug in your modem and wait until all the lights have stopped blinking.
>    - If you unplugged your router, plug it back in and wait until the lights have stopped blinking.
>    - Turn on your computer or mobile device and try playing your video.
> 4. Check your extensions, plugins, cache, and cookies 
>     Some video issues are caused by Chrome extensions, plugins, or something saved in
>      your cache or browser data. Learn how to troubleshoot and fix the
>      problem: 
>     **Check extensions and plugins**
>
>    - To see if an extension is causing problems, try playing the video you're having trouble with in Incognito mode. Learn more about
>        incognito mode.
>    - If that solved your issue, turn off your extensions or plugins temporarily. Then turn them back on one-by-one to see which extension
>        or plugin is causing the problem.
>    - If this doesn't work, try resetting Chrome to its default settings. This will turn off your extensions and plugins. 
>       **Clear
>        cache and cookies**
>    - Check to see if the video will play in an Incognito window in Chrome. If it does play, you may need to clear your cache and browsing
>        data. Learn how to clear your cache and browsing data.
>    - Note:/ Keep in mind that clearing your cache and cookies erases your settings for websites. Here are some examples:
>    - If you chose to have sites remember your username and password, they will be cleared from your browser's memory when you clear cache and
>        cookies. You'll have to sign in to these sites again. Websites might
>        load a little slower because all of the images and content pieces have
>        to be loaded from scratch.